# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function esc_url()

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am having trouble identifying the problem within my code. I am using code from WordPress Content Management System:

```
    <?php
include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Registration Form</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Registration form to be output if the POST variables are not
        set or if the registration script caused an error. -->
        <h1>Register with us</h1>
        <?php
        if (!empty($error_msg)) {
            echo $error_msg;
        }
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li>Usernames may contain only digits, upper and lower case letters and underscores</li>
            <li>Emails must have a valid email format</li>
            <li>Passwords must be at least 6 characters long</li>
            <li>Passwords must contain
                <ul>
                    <li>At least one upper case letter (A..Z)</li>
                    <li>At least one lower case letter (a..z)</li>
                    <li>At least one number (0..9)</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Your password and confirmation must match exactly</li>
        </ul>
        <form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" 
                method="post" 
                name="registration_form">
            Username: <input type='text' 
                name='username' 
                id='username' /><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
            Password: <input type="password"
                             name="password" 
                             id="password"/><br>
            Confirm password: <input type="password" 
                                     name="confirmpwd" 
                                     id="confirmpwd" /><br>
            <input type="button" 
                   value="Register" 
                   onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password,
                                   this.form.confirmpwd);" /> 
        </form>
        <p>Return to the <a href="index.html">login page</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I am receiving an error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function esc_url() in /var/www/html/register.php. This function is here to sanitizes the output from the PHP_SELF server variable: Here is my function for this:

```
function esc_url($url) {

    if ('' == $url) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = (string) $url;

    $count = 1;
    while ($count) {
        $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
    }

    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

    $url = htmlentities($url);

    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

    if ($url[0] !== '/') {
        // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        return '';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

I cannot find where there would be an error thrown within these two codes.

Comment: What file is your function declared in

Comment: Like @VBCPP is suggesting, check if you're including the right file that should remove the issue, if not, echo a line in the included file to see if PHP actually included it.

Comment: I wonder if you don't have to add `require_once 'wp-includes/formatting.php';` on your code; allegedly, that's where  [esc_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) seems to be defined...

Answer (score 1):

You said that function is present in the file

```
/var/www/html/register.php
```

But you are including

```
include_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
```

Which is not the correct filename. If you  had used `require_once`, you would have found out that error yourself. Change that `include` to `require` and get the error message.

```
require_once 'includes/register.inc.php';
require_once 'includes/functions.php';
```

**Edit**

Seems like I overread the error message and register.php is not the file which should be included. But this answer will still stand here and not be deleted because the error is still due to the same issue.

If you encounter a message that a function is undefined, it simply is undefined. And that only means neither its present in the current file nor in any included file. And certainly that Is not a PHP core function.

Comment: You can clearly see that that is the file in which the error is outputted, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: You're right about that misunderstanding. But that is still the answer. Let's wait and find out

Comment: Just that some people don't come back to tell us whether it worked or not :)